# My old files are lost?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I used to have Windows XP in my computer. When I was trying Ubuntu 12.04 I was able to see the old files, but when I installed Ubuntu I can't found them anymore. Any clues?

The Disk Utility shows my disk with 4 partitions:

```
/dev/sda1 107 GB Ext 4 File System Linux Ox83 Bootable Not mounted
/dev/sda2 53 GB Container for logical partitions
/dev/sda6 51 GB Ext 4 File system Ext 4 (version 1.0)
/dev/sda5 2.7 GB Swap Space
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any Windows partitions on the disk anymore, so most likely your files are gone, unless you have more than one hard drive in the machine.

I suspect you installed Ubuntu using the "Use the whole disk" option instead of "Install alongside existing OS".

Comment: This seems to be the case. If there was important data on there it might be wise to consult [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).